# What url parameters does stripe allow me to pass back after a payment?

Tags: stripe-payments

First time using stripe to handle payments and I cant find the relevant document telling my what url parameters I can send back to our confirmation page.

We're using the payment link option and once payment has been taken it directs to a page on our website - the only thing I can find to append to the custom redirect url is session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID} but that doesnt tell me who the payment belongs to - I need to send back the email address or something i can identify the user with

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you mean by "payment link option".

If it's [Stripe Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=web&ui=checkout), you can set any query param in the `success_url` argument.

If it's [Payment Links](https://stripe.com/docs/payment-links/share), you would need to set the query params in the actual Payment Link, e.g.:
`https://buy.stripe.com/xxx?query_param=example`

Your query params will then be injected in the confirmation page.

That said, I think you might be looking for a way to get something that you don't have yet - here, the Customer email.
This would only be possible if you know this beforehand, and pass it as a query param with the methods outlined above.

Otherwise, you can use the native {{CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}} param, and [retrieve your Session](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/retrieve) from the backend to get the customer email and return it to your confirmation page.